# How to normalize a 3D non colored Mesh in a unit bounding box

Tags: c++, 3d, mesh

I have a 3D mesh encoded in a .OFF file. Only vertices, coordinates of these vertices and connectivity are encoded. I read in some papers that a 3D mesh can be normalized in a unit bounding box. What this really means ? and how we can do this ?

Answer (score 2):

That means the mesh will fit into space defined by axis aligned cube of size `1` for example defined by corners: `A(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)` and `B(+0.5,+0.5,+0.5)`.

To achieve this:

1. **get actual bounding box**

   So loop through all used Vertexes and remember min and max coordinate for each axis `A0(xmin,ymin,zmin),B0(xmax,ymax,zmax)`.
2. **Normalize to bounding box `A,B`**

   So loop through each Vertex again and recompute them (by linear interpolation). For example like this:

   ```
   Vertex[i].x=A.x + (B.x-A.x)*(Vertex[i].x-A0.x)/(B0.x-A0.x)
   Vertex[i].y=A.y + (B.y-A.y)*(Vertex[i].y-A0.y)/(B0.y-A0.y)
   Vertex[i].z=A.z + (B.z-A.z)*(Vertex[i].z-A0.z)/(B0.z-A0.z)
   ```

   The problem is that this will not respect aspect ratios. In case you need the mesh preserves it then you need to change this to:

   ```
   scale = min((B.x-A.x)/(B0.x-A0.x)),
               (B.y-A.y)/(B0.y-A0.y),
               (B.z-A.z)/(B0.z-A0.z))
   Vertex[i].x=(Vertex[i].x-0.5*(A0.x+B0.x))*scale+0.5*(A.x+B.x)
   Vertex[i].y=(Vertex[i].y-0.5*(A0.y+B0.y))*scale+0.5*(A.y+B.y)
   Vertex[i].z=(Vertex[i].z-0.5*(A0.z+B0.z))*scale+0.5*(A.z+B.z)
   ```

   Hope I did not make any mistake as I derived it right in the SO/SE editor. The idea is to compute the max `scale` that is not exceeding new bounding box size (largest mesh axis size will fit exactly into new bounding box) and then just rescale the Mesh while center of old bounding box will be center of new bounding box too.

   Some meshes also include their own transform matrices. In that case you can encode this transformation directly to this matrix leaving the vertexes as are. But usually if mesh normalization is required then it is because some Vertexes manipulation needs it and is usually better to change the vertexes ...